# JKS File got corrupted while trying to download from AWS windowsInstance

Tags: java, windows, powershell, keystore, aws-ssm

I have a case where my test.jks file resides in AWS-Winodws Instance, and I need to download it to my local machine via SSMAgent.

Below Shellscript command is used to download file as Base 64 encoded content.
For all other files below command working fine.But when it comes to jks My file got corrupted while decoding.Also Im getting below error while trying to open in keytool.

> keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

download:

```bsh
$Content1 = get-content <filename> -Raw  \n [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Content1))
```

Note : I have observed the file size varies from the original file...

I am wondering, am I missing something here

Comment: The sample code doesn't make sense. The upload part converts _from_ base64 _to_ plaintext, so hello.txt will contain string `Hello World` instead of its encoded version. What's more, the download part is not working code.

Comment: No..I have just attached sample as hello world here...Actual use case is I have done same procedure for jks file content as well...but while trying to write jks file content same as above  Im facing issue